Could a planet have metalloids but very few metals?
Could advanced technology be created by an intelligent species on a planet where there are very few true metals and only large amounts of metalloids? I envision a planet sparse in accessible metals, mostly all silicates (chiefly boron, silicone, germanium, tellurium) where most heavy metals have seeped to the core and are largely inaccessible or have been concentrated within the metal-hungry bacteria that live within roots of certain plants.
Really appreciate any help provided! :D THANK YOU!

This question is asking multiple different questions in one. Please separate out requests into separate questions. For example, "is this possible" and "what technologies could be produced in this circumstance" are different questions, with different answers, as well as the questions about the moons and climate.

Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding! Here on Earth the tides due to the Sun are about half as large as those due to the Moon. Pretty decent, I would say... Otherwise, please be aware that this site has a strict policty of allowing only one question per question.

Thanks, I amended the post!

The question is still asking too many questions. 1. Can a planet have few metals 2. What technologies could they develop with limited metals. 3. What technologies could people develop with metalloids?

Ah thank you, I did not want to overwhelm the forum with three questions when the three I posed were so similar. BUT thank you for letting me know and apologies if it was still too verbose, next time I will break Qs into separate threads.

This question does not ask multiple questions in one.

First, let's address the issues how to make a planet that is metal scarce
This method will not produce your desired result

...or have been concentrated within the metal-hungry bacteria that live within roots of certain plants.

This will make metal ores more available to your civilization, not less so.  Something like this already happens on Earth with Thiobacillus bacteria.  This bacteria absorbs iron from the environment and concentrates, then when it dies off and dries out it forms a kind of rock called Goethite (AKA: Bog Iron) which becomes one of the highest quality sources of iron ore on the planet.  Not only does this bacteria make good ore, but it makes it close to the surface of the planet making it easy to mine. This kind of Iron Ore was the first source of iron humans learned to smelt, meaning that it's existence accelerated our iron age, not held it back.
So it is better for your setting if you actually eliminate metal hungry bacteria from your ecosystem, because this will make it harder for ores to consolidate into economically useful concentrations.
How to Maximize the effectiveness of distillation

...where most heavy metals have seeped to the core and are largely inaccessible...

Because metals tend towards a higher density than non-metals, this method would produce your desired result.  That said, for your planet to achieve a significant level of distillation, it will need to be significantly more tectonically active in its past, much older than Earth, and preferably more massive meaning it will probably need to be a very old Super Earth orbiting a small, long-lived class of star like an orange or red dwarf.
Other Things that can contribute to low metal content
Different elements come from different kinds of cosmic events.  The hardest metals to make scarce on your planet will actually be the most economically useful ones because they are relatively plentiful in the universe and because they have lower densities than other metals, they are harder to eliminate via distillation.  So, if you put your planet somewhere that there are negligible remnants from exploding white dwarfs, then you can significantly select against things like Chromium, Manganese, Iron, Cobalt, Nickel, Copper, and Zinc without selecting against the metalloids slightly higher on the periodic table like Germanium and Arsenic.  That said, Silicon, Sulfur, and Calcium would also see notable reductions in concentrations, but overall it would be the 4th level metals that would be the most impacted by this change.
You can also address the sources of ore consolidation.  Ore is a mineral that has an unusually high concentration of a given element which normally results from tectonic activity, the various effects of rain water, or biological accumulation.  So a small, dry, dead planet might be overall more rich in surface metals that a highly volcanic Super Earth, but it could all be too evenly distributed to be useful... but such a planet is probably not a great candidate for life.
You could also try making it an icey plant instead of a rocky planet.  This would make burying all metals deep enough to be impossible to reach pretty easy, but it would also make things like boron, silicone, germanium, and tellurium far less accessible, too.
The other thing you can do is progenitor civilizations.  If an advanced civilization arrived on your planet long ago, they may have mined away a lot of the "useful" elements and exported them for use on some other planet or megastructure. Not only does this allow you to selectively remove/keep what you want, but it specifically has the biggest impact on element concentrations in the outer crust which other explanations would struggle a lot to achieve.
As for the advanced technology thing
Shy of using an ice planet, you might be able to slow tech development down by making certain things a bit more expensive and uncommon, but probably not stop it all together.  Humans mine and process ores which only exist in parts per million if the material matters to us enough; so, if we had to get our metals from really poor quality ores like river sands containing 5-10% iron instead of good ores like Hematite and Goethite which can contain 60-70% iron, than we would.  Infact, this is exactly what happened in Feudal Japan.  Despite Japan being one of the most iron poor places on Earth, they still developed a thriving iron economy, and even became well known for the quality of steel products that they were able to produce from locally refined sands.  The cost of refinement made iron more rare there, but as long as you have enough fuel to burn and enough rocks to work with, you can refine just about element from any mineral.
The thing is that there is nothing you can do to how a planet forms that can make it so poor in metal that those metals will never be exploited without also making Boron, Silicone, Germanium, Tellurium inaccessible ... and even if you did, there is still the issue of meteoric sources of metals that will always ensure that the planet has some good sources of metals near the surface.
Perhaps you could change the people instead of the planet
If you want a civilization that makes better use of non-metallic elements, it's probably better to change the values of the culture than the planet itself.  Humans value metals because we so highly prize tools and weapons, but what if your indigenous species had natural tools like claws and teeth that they could do most of the early civilization stuff with thier own body parts.  Then they would instead prize materials that can be used to build structures, vessels, and clothing far above tools and weapons.  Ceramics, carpentry, resin making, textiles, brick making, and glass blowing could dwarf the importance of metalworking in thier early civilization so that as they become more advanced, they simply learn to solve more problems using things they are already experts at working with.
Things we make out of steel and aluminum, they may choose to make out of high quality fibreglass or impregnated fabrics.  Eventually, they will hit a point where they need to use every element on the periodic table for something, but by the time they really start to study metallurgy, it will be several millennia behind the times leading them to still prefer other materials in most cases.


Thank you for the note about the metal-hungry bacteria, and yes I was basing that notion off of Leptospirillum ferriphilum or Magnetospirillum magneticum. My thought process was the the bacteria over millennia had consumed most of the easily accessible metals and deposited within the roots of a specific tree species and vine species (symbiotic trio in a sense). So the amounts would be relatively small, but also locked away in the trees that are considered sacred (that's another story haha) and therefore inaccessible.




My planet would have a small F class star (binary with a large K class as well), so I might want to ditch that then due to the longevity of the planet?


Thanks for the link! I believe option one would be ideal here by placing in a white dwarf star void area, but the progenitor idea is very alluring accept for the fact that I am trying my hand at a quasi-fantasy style book, so space travel may not be possible, although I have not ruled out that notion yet, still on the fence of how it could pan out.



@ZipZap The "Progenitor race" don't have to be space faring.  They could be some kind of interdimensional monsters, or otherwise something that can portal between worlds to steal resources.  Or you could have a race  that live on another continent or underground that hoards the world's metals to themselves, raiding others like vikings whenever someone starts to amass too much.


Thanks for those notes, I am just kind of reaching for the moon here trying to make a society where there is a society that focuses on biological/genetic advancements because metals are scarce to develop synthetic tech. Sort of like in Semiosis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiosis_(novel)) where glass and stone was advanced. I may have to default to metals I suppose.
I really like your notion here. I am striving for genetics and the development of the mind as their chief advancements, with as you said for glass, fiberglass, resin, ceramics, stone etc.
Thanks again for your help! :)


I like that Idea, I have been on the fence about the idea of paths like the Silfen (https://peterfhamilton.fandom.com/wiki/Silfen) and the idea of Yggdrasil or the Faraway Trees from the TV show From (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJahqSg6x4s&themeRefresh=1).

@Nosajimiki I was curious, too, about ensuring that heavy-metal-rich meteorites are kept clear of the planet once the initial heavy metals are distilled toward the core; would that be an important factor? Or too small to really matter? I also wondered about the feasibility of superconducting technology being a significant drive for these people, since they would lack the metals for good conduction at ambient?

@Amocito The big thing meteorites bring is meteoric steel which is a naturally occuring, already smealted and ready to use form of iron.  It does not come in industrially useful quantities, but it can provide enough material to help an early civilization get a head start into metalworking.  As for superconductors: it would be even harder to make useful than it is for use, but once they figure out graphene, they would have a good ambient conductor to work with.

The development of the Humanity could be exactly the same until the late stone age.
Metalhungry bacteria could be collected, burned, and the result would be a large part metal ore. That already could be reduced by coal. I think if metalhungry bacteria eat the metals, that would more likely a helper of the humanity, a concetrator of the scarce metal sources.
I think it would be more realistic if only the iron and copper ores are practically nonexistent. Note, there is still a lot of aluminium in the soil, but it is no way to extract that with roughly late 1800s technology.
Question is, what could have been done if there is no really way to extract metals. Here you can see the most important developments of the humanity. Funny thing is, there is nothing really unreplaceable until the middle 18th century, the steam machine.
Of course, for example, agriculture without metal tools would be much lesser effective and that had a negative effect to the population, but it would work. Nearly everything would work. Of course, everything had been lesser quality, more work intensive.
The only problem is the steam engine. That simply can not happen without metals. However, only a century later, we had discovered coke and with that, we could have reduced even the soil (well... most soils) into metals.
Beside that, important things like sulfuric acid, were known even a millennia before.
These, with costly and in low quantity, but could have produced the first metals what human eye can see. And we had known on the spot, how important is it, to have the first swords (in the 1800s...)
The discovery of the metal production had been surely counted like the industrial revolution today.
I think the development of the humanity had been much more slow, but the ultimate result had been very similar as today. Yes, of course everything steel or aluminium would be much more costly, our life standards would be lower, but our world would be essentially the same.
